# Deleted Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

There was a data extension that has been deleted. Is there any way to restore this DE or query off of what was deleted?

Comment: You would have to contact support to see if restoration is possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in the Marketing Cloud interface. However, I had the problem that a journey disappeared and support was able to restore it. This should also apply for data extensions. So I suggest creating a support case immediately with highest priority, as I don't know how long the data extension can be restored.

As has been mentioned in the comments due to security/privacy policies there is a risk, that only the data extension structure can be recovered, but not the data itself.
Would be great id you could comment if you had any luck with the data @Amanda1111.

Comment: Due to new security/privacy policies, they can recover the structure of the DE, but I believe the data inside of the DE is not recoverable through support.

Comment: Thank you for that insight, I added it to the answer!

Comment: well, no luck recovering the DE. I imported the original file and then queried against the _sent data view to get the info I needed. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the data was cleared.

If you did a query overwrite, it drops the DE completely and do not believe this is easily recoverable.

If you pressed Clear Data, then open a ticket and indicate this information to the support agent.  This still requires a specialized team to assist as the data is not exposed to the MC Support Agent.