# How to recover deleted data extensions from Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, subscriber, email-studio, undelete

Data extensions are mistakenly deleted from our Marketing Cloud instance. Is there any way to recover it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Data Extensions are only soft-deleted and are retained for a period of time. Create a case with Support to request re-instatement of the Data Extension that's been mistakenly deleted.

Comment: not sure if that is still the case but I would definitely try with support;
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272801/deleted-data-extension

Comment: @JonasLamberty Yes. I'm assuming the entire table(s) was deleted, in which case SFMC Support has a Manage tool to reinstate the tables renamed with double-underscore prefixes and marked as deleted. If the data within the table was deleted or overwritten, I agree, it's a completely different matter.